# Mark a type as "dirty" so that a new instance is created

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unity-container

I use Unity to inject a DbContext in lots of places requiring it in my code. Since it's a web application, I use the PerRequestLifeTimeManager.
However I have a situation in which I do bulk inserts and need to recreate the DbContext frequently.

The situation is the following :

```
public class TypeA
{
    public void Do()
    {
        TypeB variable = new TypeB();
        variable.EncapsulatedOperation();
    }
}

public class TypeB
{
    public void EncapsulatedOperation()
    {
        //Call unity behind the scene to resolve a service, resolving the DbContext with Unity
    }   
}
```

The depth in Type B can even grow bigger, as very often the service will instantiate objects of Type C and D, themselves calling other services which use Unity to Resolve the DbContext.

So what I was doing was to create a new DbContext in TypeA and inject it in the EncapsulatedOperation of type B but clearly it's not manageable, since the resolved services still use the DbContext resolved by Unity. I need some way to tell unity to create a new instance of the DbContext. In the rest of the application, the PerRequestLifeTimeManager is fine, but in this particular case, I need to be able to tell Unity exactly when I need a new instnace to be created. How can I do that ?

Comment: Why don't you create the DbContext in TypeA and inject TypeA using the constructor of TypeB?  This way TypeB can access the DbContext trough TypeA and you're sure the same DbContext is used. Also creating new instances of your DbContext isn't necessary, you can refresh and reset the data by using something like this `DbContext.Refresh(RefreshMode.KeepChanges) //RefreshMode.KeepCurrentValues or RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues` _(System.Data.Linq.RefreshMode)_

Comment: Thanks, the reason I don't do manual injection is that there are plenty of dependencies actually using the DbContext, injecting it in B won't be enough. What you say about Refresh is very interestnig, is it going to clear the context's the cache ?

Comment: You can use the Refresh method to clear the cache or update it to a more recent instance. You can even specify which table you wish to refresh, or even what row. [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534381(v=vs.110).aspx) is the documentation page and the refresh modes can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.refreshmode(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Just a update, I forgot to do, you confused DataContext, with DbContext. The Refresh() method of the ObjectContext API doesn't encapsulate the behaviour you describe